# Refactoring JUnit rules from tests

Tags: testing, junit, refactoring, code-reuse, redundancy

I have several tests and using junit with them. In all my test files I have the junit @Rule statements. like:

```
public @Rule
TestWatcher resultReportingTestWatcher = new TestWatcher(this);
```

This and few other statements exist in all my test files. This repetion of code bothers me a little, since I think these lines can be moved to a separate place and can be used from there.

I am not very sure if this can be done, as I am very new to `junit`.
Need giudence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put common `Rule`s in a parent class:

```
public class AbstractTest {
    @Rule public SomeRule someRule = new SomeRule();
}
public class YourTest extends AbstractTest {
    @Test public void testMethod() {
        someRule.blah();
        // test some things
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Also, can this `@Rule` statement be used inside some condition? For example: I want this statement to be executed only if some condition is true.

Comment: No, it can't - JUnit reflectively goes through your test class and invokes any `@Rule`s before running your test (or any `@Before` methods for that matter).

Comment: You can create your own rule, which considers the condition.

Comment: @StefanBirkner: Can you please refer some good tutorial for creating my own `@Rule` annotations.

Comment: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2009/10/04/junit-rules/ It's a good start, but be beware that MethodRule is replaced by TestRule. You can also have a look at the source code of [System Rules](https://github.com/stefanbirkner/system-rules), which is a library of simple rules. [JUnit's org.junit.rules package](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/tree/master/src/main/java/org/junit/rules) has some example rules, too.